# Как управлять svg, подгруженное через object посредством JS

Tags: javascript, svg, объекты

Есть объект в HTML с SVG:

`<object class="service classic" id="classic" type="image/svg+xml" data="../img/classic.svg"></object>`

Хочу изменить какой либо атрибут с помощью `JS`, ничего не получается, подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?
Вот код JS:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var object = document.getElementById("classic");
  var svgDocument = object.contentDocument;
  var svgb1 = svgDocument.getElementsByClassName("st0");
  var svgb2 = svgDocument.getElementsByClassName("st1");
  svgb1[0].setAttribute("fill", "yellow");
  svgb2[0].setAttribute("fill", "red");
};
```

Comment: В Хроме не работает с файлами диска из за политики безопасности. На сайтах всё работает. Для разработчиков можно отключить это в хроме, запустив его с опцией --disable-web-security --user-data-dir.

Comment: У меня код работает. Уточните пожалуйста где у вас находится тестовая страница (локально или на сервере). Какой веб браузер? Может проблема с содержимым svg или неправильно указан путь к файлу?